# Need help using an if else statement and a loop together. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning JavaScript and I'm trying to have an if else statement declare something, but I want to use a loop with it. Basically something like this:

```
var myNum = 1;
var linebreak = "<br />";
var d3d = "You're very lucky! ^_^";
var p3p = "<p>Too Bad. Maybe Next Time.</p>";
for (myNum = 0; myNum < 7; myNum++) {
    if (myNum == 7) {
        document.write(myNum + linebreak + d3d + myNum);
    } else {
        document.write(p3p + "You're not very lucky today...");
    };
}
```

It would say You're not very lucky for the first 6 loops, but at the 7th loop it would say you're very lucky. I know something is wrong, because if it was written correctly, then at the end of the loop it would write the if statement. I know you'd usually have the for loop variable set as "i", but I also need the if else statement to be able to know what that is. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop never actually reaches 7 because your condition is to continue if `myNum` is below 7. To keep it at seven iterations and do what you want, you'd have to check to see `if (myNum == 6)`. On a side note, to understand loops better, you can try running this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    alert(i);

for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    alert(i);
```

Comment: I figured it out the second you answered, but yes. It's because it doesn't reach 7. I needed to have myNum <= 7, instead of myNum < 7.

Comment: If this answer helped you, don't forget to consider choosing it as the solution to your question by clicking the green checkmark to the left. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I was actually waiting for the 8 minute timer to finish lol, but I clicked it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, just making sure new users know how the site works :)